# How to connect to github only for public repositories?

Tags: github

I'd like to register for some nice services (e.g. codeclimate.com, david-dm.org) but linking to my github accounts asks for permission to access my public repositories (sure, they're public after all) and private ones (huh, no way).

I don't see where I can specify I only want to grant access to my public repositories. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, those services should ideally let you choose which repos you want to give them permission to access. That said, when you get to the GitHub authorization page, you should find in the URL a section like:

- `scope=user%3Aemail%2Crepo` (in the case of `codeclimate.com`)
- `scope=repo,user:email` (in the case of `david-dm.org`)

Now in the location bar, edit the URL, changing `repo` to `public_repo`. (Here's the full list of [GitHub scopes](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes), if you're interested.) Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you should see the GitHub authorization page requesting access to public repos only, so you can now click the `Authorize application` button.

Keep in mind that you can't always arbitrarily choose what scopes to grant an application in this way, since the application might not be designed to handle your changes. In this case, it works because these particular applications weren't written in such a way that they verified that the scopes they were granted actually matched the scopes they requested, and limiting access to public repos just presents them with a different (but still valid) view of the repo data.